# Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am following this tutorial http://www.bitfusion.io/2016/08/31/training-a-bird-classifier-with-tensorflow-and-tflearn/
I assume that training was done but the system was restarted so I can't verify if the 100 epochs were done. Can you please suggest fixes?

```
mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/python_playground$ python infer.py test_images/
bird_african_fish_eagle.jpg          bird_mount_bluebird.jpg              not_a_bird_creativecommons_logo.jpg  
bird_bullocks_oriole.jpg             not_a_bird_airplane.jpg              not_a_bird_stop_sign.jpg             
mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/python_playground$ python infer.py test_images/not_a_bird_stop_sign.jpg 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K40c
major: 3 minor: 5 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.745
pciBusID 0000:03:00.0
Total memory: 11.92GiB
Free memory: 11.85GiB
W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:590] creating context when one is currently active; existing: 0x3771170
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 1 with properties: 
name: Tesla K40c
major: 3 minor: 5 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.745
pciBusID 0000:83:00.0
Total memory: 11.92GiB
Free memory: 11.85GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:777] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 0 and 1
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:777] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 1 and 0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 1 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y N 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 1:   N Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K40c, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: Tesla K40c, pci bus id: 0000:83:00.0)
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/summaries.py:46 in get_summary.: scalar_summary (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-11-30.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.summary.scalar. Note that tf.summary.scalar uses the node name instead of the tag. This means that TensorFlow will automatically de-duplicate summary names based on the scope they are created in. Also, passing a tensor or list of tags to a scalar summary op is no longer supported.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/summaries.py:46 in get_summary.: scalar_summary (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-11-30.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.summary.scalar. Note that tf.summary.scalar uses the node name instead of the tag. This means that TensorFlow will automatically de-duplicate summary names based on the scope they are created in. Also, passing a tensor or list of tags to a scalar summary op is no longer supported.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py:766 in create_summaries.: merge_summary (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-11-30.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.summary.merge.
WARNING:tensorflow:VARIABLES collection name is deprecated, please use GLOBAL_VARIABLES instead; VARIABLES will be removed after 2017-03-02.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py:130 in __init__.: initialize_all_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed after 2017-03-02.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.global_variables_initializer` instead.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K40c, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: Tesla K40c, pci bus id: 0000:83:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K40c, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: Tesla K40c, pci bus id: 0000:83:00.0)
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py:378 in restore.: initialize_all_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed after 2017-03-02.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.global_variables_initializer` instead.
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "infer.py", line 44, in <module>
    model.load("bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/models/dnn.py", line 227, in load
    self.trainer.restore(model_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py", line 379, in restore
    self.restorer.restore(self.session, model_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1388, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 964, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_14 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_14/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_14/shape_and_slices)]]
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_21/_17 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_158_save_1/RestoreV2_21", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'save_1/RestoreV2_14', defined at:
  File "infer.py", line 43, in <module>
    model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=0, checkpoint_path='bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/models/dnn.py", line 57, in __init__
    session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py", line 125, in __init__
    keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours=keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1000, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1030, in build
    restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 624, in build
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 361, in _AddRestoreOps
    tensors = self.restore_op(filename_tensor, saveable, preferred_shard)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 200, in restore_op
    [spec.tensor.dtype])[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 441, in restore_v2
    dtypes=dtypes, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_14 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_14/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_14/shape_and_slices)]]
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_21/_17 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_158_save_1/RestoreV2_21", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]

[1]+  Killed                  python2 infer.py ${f} 2> /dev/null
mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/python_playground$ ls *50912(
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/python_playground$ ls *50912*
bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912.data-00000-of-00001  bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912.index  bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912.meta
```

Here are the dumped training files I have http://pastebin.com/9RF58yBB

Comment: We've had issues with relative paths in the past. Could you specify an absolute path for the log directory?

Comment: @drpng you mean TensorFlow team had issue with relative paths? I was also told there is a version inconsistency between tflearn and tensorflow because I am using the latest version but I do need to use the latest version for another project

Comment: I mean that it tensorflow did not always work well with relative paths in some cases. Anyway, try the absolute path.

Comment: Absolute paths were necessary for restoring my tensorflow model!

Comment: That may be the saver version problem：try define `saver` like this： `saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables(), write_version=tf.train.SaverDef.V1)`

Answer (score 14):

I just had the same problem. 
The problem is in this line:

```
model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=0, checkpoint_path='bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt')
```

Giving the checkpoint file name is not enough, you need to give the path. 
If the checkpoint file is in the working directory, you can simply change it to

```
model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=0, checkpoint_path='./bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt')
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 5):

Just got the same Error message when loading my model in Colab.

For me it where brackets in my filename, which the `save()` command can handle but `load_model()` can't.

Comment: Thanks! This totally saved me, I had squared brakes in my file name.

Comment: Is there a workaround to force it to load with square brackets in the name?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. Just use "./test_images/" instead of test_images/ in any path attributes. This helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading your `bird-classifier.tfl.ckpt-50912` model from the site and paste files into the folder (worked in my case):

```
C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Temp\tfhub_modules\87c08e811d90a898c320e6626614764b3f4e562b\variables
```